# How can I use a Sharepoint server as the Source for Inno Setup files?

Tags: sharepoint, inno-setup

I'm using Inno Setup for an application setup.  Many of the data files that will be included with this application are stored on a Microsoft Sharepoint server.  When I try to use the path Sharepoint provides in the 'Source:'

```
[Files]
Source: http://teams/sm/Symbols/*; DestDir: {app}\Symbols
```

I get the following error on compile:

> Unknown filename prefix: "http:"

How can I properly call out a Sharepoint location as the source for my data files?

I'm using Inno Setup version 5.4.2

**EDIT**

I know what the documentation says. 

 I am looking for a solution to this problem.  I am using InnoSetup, the files are on SharePoint; how can I make this work?

**EDIT 2**

Thanks to brian brinley.  Below is the exact syntax that I used in InnoSetup thanks to his answer:

```
[Setup]
SourceDir=\\teams\sm

[Files]
Source: \Symbols\*; DestDir: {app}\Symbols
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SharePoint Libraries support WebDav so you can go to the library that is containing your setup files and open with explorer. Since you didn't specify which version of sharepoint, here are both options.

SharePoint 2010 - open the library, click on the library tools/library tab in the ribbon, and select "Open with Explorer"

SharePoint 2007 - Open the library, click on actions and then select open with windows explorer.

Once you open in explorer you will have the path. If it opens with http:// you can simply replace with \ i.e.. \myServer\myLibraryName

Comment: Sweet Mother of Abraham Lincoln, It worked!  I edited my question to show the exact syntax that I used in the InnoSetup file.  Thanks Brian!

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported by Inno Setup. You should download your files from SharePoint and then create the installer (maybe you can create a script for this).

Here's more information on what you actually can put in the [[Files] section](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_filessection.htm).

Web installations are not supported either: [Is there a "web install" feature?](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isfaq.php#webinstall)

Answer (score 1):

As alfonso said, it's not supported by Inno, you will need to use a 3rd party app/script to download them, possibly something like wget.

This can either be done as a pre compile step in your build script or by using ISPP's `Exec()` function to download each in turn as they're needed.

As for the wildcard, this is not supported by HTTP at all so you will need some form of file list containing each one to get, or use wget's recursive download with a single index page.

(Note that I don't use SharePoint so I can only talk about the Inno part of it.